# How to avoid failing with Decimal function when 0/0 occurs?

Tags: python, linux, decimal

I have a Python 2.7 script and it uses two lists and divides the numbers to each other then creates a new list with the results and it is working fine but it errors on the line below anytime the script has to divide 0 / 0, which happens sometimes depending on the state of my current servers. Is there any way to avoid this?

```
complist =[a, b, c]
totallist=[d, e, f]

percentlist = [Decimal(c) / Decimal(t) * 100 for c,t in zip(complist, totallist)]
```

I am getting error:

```
    MacBook-Pro-3$ python dailyReport.py 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dailyReport.py", line 67, in <module>
    percentlist = [Decimal(l) / Decimal(t) * 100 for l,t in zip(complist, totallist)] 
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 1321, in __truediv__
    return context._raise_error(DivisionUndefined, '0 / 0')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 3873, in _raise_error
    raise error(explanation)
decimal.InvalidOperation: 0 / 0
```

Comment: What should the output be for those values? Have you tried adding some error handling?

Comment: Avoid it in what way? Be specific. Should some value be substitued and the rest of the values computed?

Comment: dividing by 0 is not allowed in python, you need to use `try:` and `except:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
percentlist = [0 if t == 0 else Decimal(c) / Decimal(t) * 100 for c,t in zip(complist, totallist)]
```

Answer (score -1):

use `try` and `except`

```
try:
    complist =[a, b, c]
    totallist=[d, e, f]

    percentlist = [Decimal(c) / Decimal(t) * 100 for c,t in zip(complist, totallist)]

except decimal.InvalidOperation:
    print 'divide by zero error'
```

**EDIT**

If you want to add it in new list use that.

```
newlist = []
try:
    complist =[a, b, c]
    totallist=[d, e, f]

    percentlist = [Decimal(c) / Decimal(t) * 100 for c,t in zip(complist, totallist)]

except decimal.InvalidOperation:
    newlist.append(0)
```

Comment: Sorry I shouldve clarified, I also need the script to just make that value in the new list 0 if it is 0 / 0 if possible

Comment: Check the edit if that what you meant .. if you want any specific value in list or just the zero ?

Comment: I tried both mention ways above, but it still gives me the same error as before with :raise error(explanation) , decimal.InvalidOperation: 0 / 0

Comment: now it will work my bad, previously added wrong exception, I tried it and working for me now check at your side...

Comment: Bare `except:` statements are dangerous because they catch **everything** including syntax errors. Always better to be specific to avoid hiding problems. In this case `except decimal.InvalidOperation:` would be a good choice. Even `except Exception:` would be better and still very generic.

Answer (score -1):

I went to https://www.REPL.IT  and tried your code. Generally, I don't Think python allows division by ZERO. I tried your code and print(0/0), and it returns an error

Comment: But of course, if that's the objective of your code, listen to @Aafaque Abdullah